# Interesting subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ [CMI 2019]

Tags: vector-spaces

Cosider the vector space $V=M_n(\mathbb C)$ and $W$ be a vector subspace of $V$ such that every non-zero element of $W$ is invertible. Show that dim$W=1$.

I know that any matrix over $\mathbb C$ is triangulable. I assumed that dim$W$ is 2, Can I show that this gives rise to a singular matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A,B\in W$ be two linearly independent matrix, then $A^{-1}B$ is invertible (not necessarily to be in $W$). Now $A^{-1}B$ has an eigenvector $v$, corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ (the field $\mathbb{C}$ implies the existence of eigenvalue). We have $A^{-1}Bv = \lambda v$. This implies $(B-\lambda A)v = 0$ and so $B-\lambda A$ is not invertible.

Comment: That's a nice solution. Thank you. That means my logic was not sufficient?

Comment: I think we don't need to use triangulable over $\mathbb{C}$, the existence of eigenvalue is enough. Just argue by contradiction as you did.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Suppose its dimension is not one. Then it has a basis $\mathcal{B}$ which contains at least two independent invertible matrices. Call this two matrices as $A$ and $B$. Then $$(\forall k \in \Bbb C):\;A \neq kB$$ Since $W$ is a vector space, so $$(\forall k):\;A-kB \in W $$ Now consider $\det (A-kB)$ to arrive a contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint: $\det\colon W\cong\mathbb{C}^k\to\mathbb{C}$ is algebraic and obviously nonconstant.

Comment: I'm not getting anywhere with this hint please explain

Comment: $\det$ does vanish on $W$, at $0$. That this cannot be the only zero is not trivial (and needs to use that $k > 1$). Perhaps you mean to use that the vanishing set of $\det$ is codimension $1$ but that seems beyond simple linear algebra.