# Suppose that every non-zero element of $V$ is an invertible matrix.Show that $\dim_{\mathbb C} V\leqslant 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, solution-verification

Let $V$ be a subspace of the complex vector space $M_n(\mathbb C)$.

Suppose that every non-zero element of $V$ is an invertible matrix.

Show that $\dim_{\mathbb C} V \leqslant 1$.

We know that,
every $n\times n$ invertible is row equivalent to identity matrix this gives basis element of V has only one element i.e. identity matrix.
hence the dimension of $V=1$.
and if $\dim(V)=0$ the subspace is only zero matrices.

Please tell me if my argument or proof is correct or not.

[Interesting subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ [CMI 2019]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226940/interesting-subspace-of-m-n-mathbbc-cmi-2019)

Comment: It's wrong, take any invertible matrix $A\ne I$ and its span: that doesn't contain the identity matrix.

Comment: Indeed, $AB=0\nRightarrow A=0\lor B=0$, those are just _zero-divisors_ with $\det=0$

Comment: Also, check your grammar and spelling. (:

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. Suppose, say, that$$V=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}z&0\\0&2z\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,z\in\mathbb C\right\}.$$Then every non-zero element of $V$ is invertible. But it is *not* true that the set $\{\text{identity matrix}\}$ is basis of $V$, since the identity matrix does not belong to $V$.

Comment: Can you tell me basis element of this subspace?

Comment: I think you have too many *not*'s in here.

Comment: @charurama There is no such thing as **the** basis of this subspace. **One** basis is $\left\{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right\}$, for instance.

Comment: @zipirovich Sure! I've edited my answer. Thank you.